# Triangle Inequality in Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

This is an answer from Slader for *Understanding Analysis* by Abbott. The book suggests to use $a = a-b+b$ but the steps for this answer doesn't make any sense to me. For one, why does s/he write use $a=a-b+b$ when it looks like they used $a = a-b$ which doesn't seem valid because then you don't have a true statement for all $a,b$ but only when $b = 0$.

[image]

Comment: It might help you to have different letters. Write the triangle inequality as $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$. Now set $x=a-b$ and $y=b$.

Answer (score 1):

They proof is correct. They are using $a=a-b+b$. Might help to write out a few more details

\begin{align*}
|a| &= |a-b+b| \\
&= |(a-b)+b| \\
&\leq |a-b| + |b|
\end{align*}

In total, $|a| \leq |a-b|+|b|$. Now just subtract $|b|$ from both sides to get $|a|-|b| \leq |a-b|$.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to use the triangle inequality to show that

$$||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$$

which is commonly known as the reverse triangle inequality. To do this, you need to show that

$$|a|-|b| \leq |a-b|\tag{1}$$

and

$$|b|-|a|\leq |a-b|\tag{2}$$

As $a=a-b+b$, we have

$$|a|=|a-b+b| \leq |a-b| + |b|$$

and therefore

$$|a| \leq |a-b| + |b|$$

moving $ |b|$ to the LHS forms

$$|a|-|b|\leq |a-b|$$

which shows $(1)$. Similarly, for $b=b-a+a$

$$|b|=|b-a+a| \leq |b-a| + |a|$$

and therefore

$$|b| \leq |b-a| + |a|$$

moving $ |a|$ to the LHS forms

$$|b|-|a|\leq |b-a|=|a-b|$$

which shows $(2)$.